# How to paste multiple range of cells in email body using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Using below code I am able to **paste cells in range `A1:B20` in the body of the email**.

I want to **paste another range of cells `A33:B36` in the body of email just below `A1:B20` range**.

```
Sub Trigger_Email()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim StrBody As String

    StrBody = "Hello Recruitment Team," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
        "Please work on the below request details and open it for Vendor Sourcing. The details of the RRF are mentioned in the attachment." & "<br><br>"

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "vinod.sn@wellsfargo.com;mamta.b.fajalia@wellsfargo.com"
        .CC = "G=EGS-IND-SC-Managers" & ";" & Cells(5, 2)
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "RRF for Vendor Sourcing - " & Cells(3, 2)
        .HTMLBody = StrBody & rangetoHTML(rng)
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the code to transform the range into an HTML element :

```
Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    rangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub Trigger_Email() 
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range 
    Dim OutApp As Object 
    Dim OutMail As Object 
    Dim StrBody As String

    StrBody = "Hello Recruitment Team," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
    "Please work on the below request details and open it for Vendor Sourcing. The details of the RRF are mentioned in the attachment." & "<br><br>"


    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A33:B36").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next



    With OutMail
        .To = "vinod.sn@wellsfargo.com;mamta.b.fajalia@wellsfargo.com"
        .CC = "G=EGS-IND-SC-Managers" & ";" & Cells(5, 2)
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "RRF for Vendor Sourcing - " & Cells(3, 2)
        .HTMLBody = StrBody & rangetoHTML(rng) & rangetoHTML(rng2)
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Copy this sub and replace your original sub with it (the Function must be left untouched).

Your way of asking implies that you have no experience with VBA at all and just use this code. If you need to advance your code in any other way, I suggest you try to understand the code so you could make edits yourself. I'm just adding little fractions here which you could easily do by yourself.

Comment: you are right. I am new to this area. Your suggestion did work with a little change.

I was getting error at  line:
".HTMLBody = StrBody & rangetoHTML(rng) & rangetoHTML(rng2)" :

I modified "Dim rng, rng2 As Range " to 
Dim rng as Range
Dim rng2 as Range

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Macro2()

Dim LastRow As Double

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Range("A1:AM" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("G2:G" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:AM" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Workbooks("Data Send").Activate
End Sub
```