# How to place body text after pasted info along with signature?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

This VBA code copies the current range starting from A1 and emails it. It works however, the body text gets put below the pasted info and there is no signature.

If I remove the body text the signature is there. How can put the body text on the top and still include the signature? My signature includes a picture.

```vb
Sub Email()

    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xEmailBody As String
    Dim xMailOut As     Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As      Outlook.Application

    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutApp =     CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

    xMailOut.To =    Worksheets("Setup").Range("V2").Value
    xMailOut.CC = Worksheets("Setup").Range("V3").Value
    xMailOut.Subject = Worksheets("Setup").Range("V4").Value
    xMailOut.body = Worksheets("Setup").Range("V5").Value

    xMailOut.display
    SendKeys "^{v}", True

    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating =    True

    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather copy-paste, covert the range to HTML and then append it with the existing body content.

```
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
set rng = Range("A1:A" & lr)

bodyContent = Worksheets("Setup").Range("V5").Value

mySignature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & SignatureName & ".htm"
signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(mySignature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

xMailOut.HTMLBody = bodyContent & "<br>" & rangeToHtml(rng) & "<br><br>" & signature
```

[For converting Range to HTML please follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099311/how-to-paste-multiple-range-of-cells-in-email-body-using-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you this works for the body portion. Body text is after my posted info. However my signature disappears. Any way to get it back?

Comment: Yes, you can also add the specific signature by reading it from the outlook configurations and append it after the body content. Please refer to the above-updated code.

Comment: Hi. So after trying this and entering in my signature name it works but in the square where my signature picture is it says “this picture can’t be displayed”. When Outlook first opens the picture is there but then seconds later it’s gone. The text is there. Anyway to have the image display? Thank you so much for your assistance by the way.

Comment: Hi. So I ended up solving it. Here is the code if anyone is interested. Thank you so much by the way @Bhoopesh Sharma for directing me to the right code

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Email()


    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Get Range of data to copy

     lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A1:J" & lr)


     strbody = Worksheets("Setup").Range("V5").Value

     On Error Resume Next

     With OutMail
         .display
         .To =     Worksheets("Setup").Range("V2").Value
         .CC =   Worksheets("Setup").Range("V3").Value
         .BCC = ""
         .Subject = Worksheets("Setup").Range("V4").Value
         .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & rangetoHTML(rng) & .HTMLBody
         .display
      End With

     On Error GoTo 0
     Set OutMail = Nothing
     Set OutApp = Nothing

    End Sub

  Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)

 ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
  ' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

     TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial    Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial   xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode =    False
      On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
rangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```